# Multiplying the values of two objects in Django Models

Tags: python, django

Hey I'm working with one Django Project, where i wanted to multiply the values of two different objects in django model and storing it to the database.

Here is My code of model

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from master.models import Supplier

class RawItem(models.Model):
    item_code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    item_Description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item_name

class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    raw_item = models.ForeignKey(RawItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    total_prize = models.PositiveIntegerField(editable=False, blank=True, null=True)
    po_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        total_prize = self.raw_item.item_price * self.quantity
        super(PurchaseOrder, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

so here i wanted to multiply item_price with quantity how to do that
thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

To set the `total_prize` for the current instanse, you should use the `self`. In your case:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.total_prize = self.raw_item.item_price * self.quantity
    #^^^
    super(PurchaseOrder, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

you can read more details [understand self in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self)

and official docs for the [class-objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects)

Comment: glad to help you, don't forget to accept the answer for others who will search for the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer is late but i hope still it will be helpful.

--->Views.py

```
from django.db.models import F

    table = PurchaseOrder.objects.all().update(total_prize = F('raw_item') * F('quantity'))
```